# How to keep same layout of .txt file when importing it into JTextArea in a Java application?

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtextarea

I have an app where I read from .txt file and than write from it into the `JTextArea`. But the problem is that the layout is not consistent (as seen on this picture:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaUmN.png]

I think that text area doesn't recognize tabulators. Can someone help me how to get the same layout in the text area as it is in .txt file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the difference is that the font on the left is monospace, and the default Java font is not. Apply a monospaced font to the text area using `setFont`. A common monospace font Courier/Courier New, but may not be available on your machine. Instead, request a monospaced font and Java should handle it for you.

```
textArea.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));
```

Answer (score 1):

The text editor is using a mono spaced font, so every character takes exactly the same space. If you use such a font yourself, you will be a happy person.